# Does localisation influence getch()?

Tags: c, windows, utf-8, internationalization, getch

I want to translate the ë character that I read using getch() to its corresponding UTF-8 code, 0xC3 0xAB.
ChatGTP gave me a function to produce this code, based on a value of 235 for ë where in my environment getch() for ë produces 137.
My environment is Windows, Code::Blocks 20.03, GNU GCC compiler.

How can I ensure that getch() returns 235 rather than 137? (And likewise for characters like ö, é etc.)
Does it have to do with local environment (Dutch Windows, US keyboard)?

I've used getch() and getwchar() involving variables declared as int, unsigned int, char and unsigned char. All of these options resulted in ë given as 137 or -119, but never in 235 what I was hoping for.

Comment: Don't rely on code generated by a lying, hallucinating chat bot...

Comment: The [`_getche`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getche-getwche?view=msvc-170) function is a very simple function. You may want to test whether using [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) instead solves your problem. That function will give you a [`KEY_EVENT_RECORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/key-event-record-str), which contains significantly more information.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. Your mentioning the underscored function _getche() pointed me to _getwch() which did the job.